# HikariCP Connection Pool immediately creates 100 connections

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have this code that uses HikariCP Connection Pool:

```
config.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
config.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", hostname);
config.addDataSourceProperty("port", portnumber);
config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", dbname);
config.addDataSourceProperty("user", username);
config.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
config.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
config.setInitializationFailFast(false);
pooledDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

I monitor connections in mysql by issuing command "Show Processlist" and I see that 100 connections is created after line:

```
pooledDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

...is run. I'm sure this is not meant to happen, right? It should create connections later when I do pooledDataSource.getConnection().

What am I doing wrong? Why is it creating 100 connections immediately??

Comment: Btw, 100 connections is probably way too many: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

Comment: The answer below is correct, right?  Please mark it so.

Comment: Try out arivu datasource org.arivu.dbds. Gradle dependency compile group: 'org.arivu', name: 'datasource', version:'1.0.2' . It has better connection pool implementation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default HikariCP runs as a fixed-sized pool.  You need to set `minimumIdle`.  That's it.

From the documentation for `minimumIdle`:

> This property controls the minimum number of idle connections that
>   HikariCP tries to maintain in the pool. If the idle connections dip
>   below this value, HikariCP will make a best effort to add additional
>   connections quickly and efficiently. However, for maximum performance
>   and responsiveness to spike demands, we recommend not setting this
>   value and instead allowing HikariCP to act as a fixed size connection
>   pool. **Default: same as maximumPoolSize**

Comment: This setting is bit risky though as it always try to maintain the minimumIdle connections which we have seen in our application that continues to force the connection establishment.  So use this with caution.

Comment: this recommendation doesn't make sense. I'm not sure who/what kind of an application wants a fixed size connection pool sized at the maximum value configured. it's supposed to be elastic ranging between min and max values configured. If there are many hosts running a given application with this pool with a bad max size value configured, this will easily eat up all the connections on the database server side. As @muruga said, this needs to be reviewed with **EXTREME CAUTION**